# How to convert video file url to base64 in ionic?

Tags: javascript, typescript, ionic3, angular6

I need to convert video url (http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/BigBuckBunny.mp4) to base64. in ionic 3.

i tried native base64 package. But it doesn't work.
also tried canvas method it shows error.

```
var c = document.createElement('canvas');
var img = document.getElementById('Img1');
c.height = img.naturalHeight;
c.width = img.naturalWidth;
var ctx = c.getContext('2d');

ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, c.width, c.height);
var base64String = c.toDataURL();
```

Comment: Wouldn't the standard `atob` and `btoa` methods work?

Comment: You want to encode 151MiB of data as a string? That's going to sink the browser. Good luck with (a) generating a string of that size easily and (b) consuming a string of that size easily. What are you trying to solve here?

Comment: it takes url as string.

Comment: Start again. "it takes url as string"?

Comment: If you are trying to base64 encode the url (a string) you should be able to use the standard `atob()` and `btoa()` methods. If you are attempting to encode the entire video - please specify why you might need that, as there might be better approaches, than using base64 for video data.

Comment: actually im trying to make a app works like youtube offline download option in ionic. the video url comes from api. i get idea from a blog that ionic have sqlite to store data that works in offline also. i convert that video to base64 and insert into sqlite and set storage limit to 500M. is im doing correctly. if it is a wrong way please guide me.

Comment: @VasilDininski help me bro.please.

Comment: You could instead save the video file as-is on the filesystem and save some meta information in sql lite - like the name and description of the video and most importantly the path to the file. Then when the app is offline it can open the video from the filesystem instead of doing any base64 conversions back and forth. For this purpose you'd need file system permissions. Take a look at the file plugin (https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/file) for saving the file on the filesystem

Comment: but video file should not be accessable or sharable via file manger or media players.

Comment: download video only accessable via my app only. how can i achive this

Comment: in youtube they encrypt video file as .exo file and store to file system. when offline they decrypt the .exo file to video file. no one can decrypt that file out side youtube app. i want to do like that.

Comment: @VasilDininski please help me i have no idea.

Comment: Obfuscation ***is not*** encryption. Just because you've done something slightly different to a normal URL, the video will be extractable. Huge amounts of time/money/thought have gone into how to protect video in the browser. Using base64 encoded URLs is not one of the solutions.

Comment: Plain and simple, encoding video data to string will not work nicely because there's simply too much data. Strings of the size you would need are enough to break browsers. **I guarantee that this is a bad idea.**

Comment: What are other good ways to do this?

Comment: @spender Please help me